# Authorization error with Google API 0Auth

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api, authorization

(This issue is fixed. John gave the correct solution in the comments.)

Hello fellow programmers. I'm trying to make a login button with authorization through Google. I want to do this through 0Auth. When I want to test it out in the browser, I get an error that says:

--> Access denied: Authorization error. The 0Auth client was not found. Error 401: invalid_client <--

I created a test clientID on the site which gave a client id number and client secret number. The test email is: elroydegans@gmail.com.   I think I am overseeing something but don't know what. The following is my code:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { Login } from "../componenten/LogIn"
import { Logout } from "../componenten/LogOut"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { gapi } from "gapi-script"

const clientId = "342462410453 - igjbmq83j1rplroap1lu8he9dua5db2b.apps.googleusercontent.com"

export const LoginPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const start = () => {
      gapi.auth2.init({
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: ""
      })
    }
    gapi.load("client:auth2", start)
    setIsSignedIn(true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="grid">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="box">
          <h1>Login</h1>
          {isSignedIn ? <Login /> : <Logout />}
          <button style={{ color: "black", borderColor: "black", border: "solid" }} onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
            Back
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

Comment: The `clientId` string value is incorrect. There are no spaces in the client ID.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnHanley! The problem is now solved! I copied it directly from the google API when I created the test account so I didn't expect there would be a fault in there. This is a good learning point for me, thanks!